# Как поменять папку, в которой будет производиться поиск файлов .txt?

Tags: python

Мне необходимо получить список названий файлов из директории saves, вот так выглядит дерево директорий:

```
-Новая папка
--saves
---file1.txt
---file2.txt
---file3.txt
--Основная программа
```

Вот код основной программы, который я нашёл в интернете:

```
import os, fnmatch
os.system("cd:'C:\\Users\\Ученик-ФМШ\\Desktop\\Игра\\saves'")
listOfFiles = os.listdir('.')
pattern = "*.txt"
for entry in listOfFiles:
    if fnmatch.fnmatch(entry, pattern):
            print (entry)
```

Примечание: количество и названия файлов в директории saves не статичны (их может быть 100, с названиями в виде абсолютно рандомных символов), при этом обязательно будет расширение .txt

Программа должна создать и вывести массив, состоящий из названий ВСЕХ этих файлов.

Comment: Если у вас есть программа, напишите чем она вас не устраивает.

Comment: В ней нет возможности выбрать другую папку, для нахождения и последующего вывода нужных мне файлов, она как бы пытается найти файл в той же папке, в которой находится программа, хотя их не существует. Она просто выводит мне пустую строку

Comment: Уберите строку `os.system("cd:'C:\\Users\\Ученик-ФМШ\\Desktop\\Игра\\saves'")` (тем более что синтаксис команды cd там не правильный), в `listOfFiles = os.listdir('.')` вместо точки укажите `'saves'` или полный путь.

Comment: `listOfFiles = os.listdir('C:\\Users\\Ученик-ФМШ\\Desktop\\Игра\\saves')`? Я бы посоветовал использовать `pathlib`

Comment: О, спасибо большое, insolor! Всё заработало как часы!  gil9red, честно, пробовал, не получилось. Пока набираю опыт в работе с файлами)))

Answer (score 0):

```
from glob import glob

print(glob('saves/*.txt')) # можно указать и глобальный путь
```